# 48v Power supply for field mixer - Marenius MM-3100

Tags: mixers

Looking at cheap field mixer on ebay Marenius MM-3100 Portable Mono Field Mixer
 , the specs say that the phantom power is equal to battery voltage. Internally the mixer takes two 9v batteries so that 18v for phantom power which will not work with my 48v mics.

Can I use a phantom power adaptor and just feed the 48v to the power supply of this unit?

Say this guy http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Phantom2Pro?utm_source=none&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=none&gclid=CMvhy9KGrrICFQVgMgodyS8Abw or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Was looking at the specs on the manufacturer page, and it seems they have two models: one that provides 18v phantom, and one that provide 48v phantom. It appears though, that you can buy a replacement circuit board to convert the 18v to 48v. [Have a look at their price sheet](http://www.marenius.se/pdf/PRICELIST2012.pdf). (item labelled "MM-3100/48PCB"). A little pricier, but it might be worth it to simplify things.

Also, keep in mind that not all microphones actually require 48v phantom power. Some will work with only 18v. You'd have to confirm in the mic's specs of course.